# ActiveRecord set field to SQL expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, spatialite

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.8 and have a number of locations represented by a latitude and a longitude. I am using the SQLite SpatiaLite extension to convert the coordinates to the well-known binary (WKB) format. My concern is how to have ActiveRecord perform the insert or update, calling the appropriate SpatiaLite conversion methods. I am looking to do something like this:

```
obj.geometry = "AsBinary(MakePoint(4, 51))"
obj.save
# ActiveRecord would now do something like:
# INSERT INTO objects (geometry) VALUES (AsBinary(MakePoint(4, 51)))
```

Is this possible with ActiveRecord?

I have already tried GeoRuby but while its able to properly read WKB blobs, it is unable to save them to the same format SpatiaLite does.

Thanks!

Comment: A note: SQLite is not suitable for production, so I would recommend switching to PostgreSQL with the PostGIS extension.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Unfortunately I don't have that luxury at the moment. I need to get this up and running with SQLite for the time being.

Comment: Not a luxury. If you don't have time to install a real multiuser DB, then you don't have time to develop this. Sorry to be harsh, but that's just the way it is.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser It's not matter of installing another database, it's matter of keeping a lot of other software that explicitly depends on SQLite in working order. Whether or not that was a practical decision in the past, these are simply the constraints I have to deal with now.

Comment: SQLite is unsuitable for production Web applications, due to its lack of concurrency support. If your production Web application is depending on it, it is a disaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching and coming up with no solution, I decided to simply leverage the raw connection to perform the actual insert:

```
rc = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
rc.execute("INSERT INTO objects (geometry)
            VALUES (MakePoint(#{obj.lng}, #{obj.lat}))")
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use GeoRuby yet, but for spatial data I used thinking-sphinx with @geodist function, and it's quite nice to use tool.

Some resources you can read about it:

- http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/geosearching.html
- http://joeyschoblaska.com/blog_posts/220-thinking-sphinx-searching-by-location-and-keyword

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks for the swift reply! While Thinking Sphinx works great for searching, I am trying to insert data in a very specific format here. As far as I can tell, Thinking Sphinx does not do that, does it?

Comment: You said that you keep location information in latitude and longitude - with Sphinx you have these fields too, but as far as I know there is no support for querying for GeoRuby Point objects.

Comment: I indeed have a set of latitudes and longitudes, but I need to convert them to the well-known binary format. I updated my question and hope its more clear now what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: For MySQL or PostgreSQL there is a spatial_adapter gem (https://github.com/fragility/spatial_adapter), but again I don't see any equvalent tool for SQLite.